# Multiple userform checkbox values

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I am trying to take the values passed from a userform that has the following checkbox options and write them to a single concatenated cell.

Scenario Options and Userform Output Cells

[image: Scenario Options and Userform Output Cells]

userform

[image: userform]

Thank you for your help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I currently have attempted this, but can only get one option to show up at a time.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame2.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D7") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame2.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

If Me.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame3.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D8") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame3.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()

If Me.CheckBox3.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame4.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D9") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame4.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()

If Me.CheckBox5.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame6.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D10") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame6.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

If Me.CheckBox6.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame5.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D11") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame5.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ctrl1 As Control

Set ctrl1 = Nothing
    
For Each ctrl1 In Me.Frame2.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl1) = "OptionButton" And ctrl1.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E7") = ctrl1.Caption
    End If
Next

Dim ctrl2 As Control

Set ctrl2 = Nothing
    
For Each ctrl2 In Me.Frame3.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl2) = "OptionButton" And ctrl2.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E8") = ctrl2.Caption
    End If
Next

Dim ctrl3 As Control

Set ctrl3 = Nothing
    
For Each ctrl3 In Me.Frame4.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl3) = "OptionButton" And ctrl3.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E9") = ctrl3.Caption
    End If
Next

Dim ctrl4 As Control

Set ctrl4 = Nothing
    
For Each ctrl4 In Me.Frame5.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl4) = "OptionButton" And ctrl4.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E10") = ctrl4.Caption
    End If
Next

Dim ctrl5 As Control

Set ctrl5 = Nothing
    
For Each ctrl5 In Me.Frame6.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl5) = "OptionButton" And ctrl5.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E11") = ctrl5.Caption
    End If
Next

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.Frame2.Visible = False
Me.Frame3.Visible = False
Me.Frame4.Visible = False
Me.Frame5.Visible = False
Me.Frame6.Visible = False
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D7") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D8") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D9") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D10") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D11") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E7") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E8") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E9") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E10") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E11") = ""

End Sub
```

updated code:

```
Const sOptions As String = "Self-Financing,Equity financing by Coppermine,Debt financing by Coppermine," & _
        "Equity Financing by External Party,Debt Financing by external party,Customer financing"

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame2.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D7") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame2.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

If Me.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame3.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D8") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame3.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()

If Me.CheckBox3.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame4.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D9") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame4.Visible = False
End If

End Sub


Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()

If Me.CheckBox5.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame6.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D10") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame6.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

If Me.CheckBox6.Value = True Then
    Me.Frame5.Visible = True
    Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D11") = 1
Else
    Me.Frame5.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        'process each list box looking for values
        Dim selectedOptions As String
        With ListBox1
                For idx = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                        If .Selected(idx) Then
                                selectedOptions = selectedOptions & .List(idx) & ","
                        End If
                Next idx
        End With
        MsgBox selectedOptions
        'save the value to your worksheet
        selectedOptions = ""
        ' repeat for all of the list boxes.
        
        'process each list box looking for values
        With ListBox2
                For idx = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                        If .Selected(idx) Then
                                selectedOptions = selectedOptions & .List(idx) & ","
                        End If
                Next idx
        End With
        MsgBox selectedOptions
        'save the value to your worksheet
        selectedOptions = ""
        ' repeat for all of the list boxes.
        
        'process each list box looking for values
        With ListBox3
                For idx = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                        If .Selected(idx) Then
                                selectedOptions = selectedOptions & .List(idx) & ","
                        End If
                Next idx
        End With
        MsgBox selectedOptions
        'save the value to your worksheet
        selectedOptions = ""
        ' repeat for all of the list boxes.
        
        'process each list box looking for values
        With ListBox4
                For idx = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                        If .Selected(idx) Then
                                selectedOptions = selectedOptions & .List(idx) & ","
                        End If
                Next idx
        End With
        MsgBox selectedOptions
        'save the value to your worksheet
        selectedOptions = ""
        ' repeat for all of the list boxes.
        
        'process each list box looking for values
        With ListBox5
                For idx = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                        If .Selected(idx) Then
                                selectedOptions = selectedOptions & .List(idx) & ","
                        End If
                Next idx
        End With
        MsgBox selectedOptions
        'save the value to your worksheet
        selectedOptions = ""
        ' repeat for all of the list boxes.
        
    
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.Frame2.Visible = False
Me.Frame3.Visible = False
Me.Frame4.Visible = False
Me.Frame5.Visible = False
Me.Frame6.Visible = False
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D7") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D8") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D9") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D10") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("D11") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E7") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E8") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E9") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E10") = ""
Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E11") = ""

        ListBox1.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        ListBox1.List = Split(sOptions, ",")
        ListBox2.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        ListBox2.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        ListBox2.List = Split(sOptions, ",")
        ListBox3.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        ListBox3.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        ListBox3.List = Split(sOptions, ",")
        ListBox4.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        ListBox4.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        ListBox4.List = Split(sOptions, ",")
        ListBox5.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        ListBox5.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        ListBox5.List = Split(sOptions, ",")

End Sub
```

Comment: @braX, thanks I just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your options in each of the 5 frames from checkboxes to listboxes.  Keep your current `UserForm_initialize` but add what is in the example below to it.  Keep your current selection for showing the 5 frames.  Change your CommandButton to process the listbox as in the example below.

Example: Create a user form and paste this code into it. Add a command button and a list box to the frame and run it to see how it works.

```
Const sOptions As String = "Self-Financing,Equity financing by Coppermine,Debt financing by Coppermine," & _
        "Equity Financing by External Party,Debt Financing by external party,Customer financing"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        'process each list box looking for values
        Dim selectedOptions As String
        With ListBox1
                For idx = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                        If .Selected(idx) Then
                                selectedOptions = selectedOptions & .List(idx) & ","
                        End If
                Next idx
        End With
        MsgBox selectedOptions
        'save the value to your worksheet
        selectedOptions = ""
        ' repeat for all of the list boxes.
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        ' repeat this setup for each of the frame's content, with a unique List Box in each
        ListBox1.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        ListBox1.List = Split(sOptions, ",") ' set the values for the list box
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry I am new to VBA coding but how would I save the value to my worksheet in your example above?

Comment: Also, how would I repeat this code for each List Box?

Comment: each listbox, when added to a form, get a unique name.  While you can change that to whatever name you want, you don't need to. While creating your user form press F4 to show the Properties Window.  The first line is the "name" of whatever is selected on the Form.  To repeat the code for each list box, just copy what is shown for ListBox1 and paste that into the Sub.  Then change the name to be the next one (ie ListBox2).

Comment: You already have code to save the value to your worksheet, Change this line `Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E11") = ctrl5.Caption` to instead reference `=selectedOptions`

Comment: After each list box is processed, change these two lines `MsgBox selectedOptions
        'save the value to your worksheet` to be `Sheets("Project Analysis - Summary").Range("E7") = selectedOptions`, Change the Range  value for each worksheet save to reference the correct cell.